Avoid breakpage between content and legend in colorbox
Situation : I use a tcolorbox, but sometimes the content and the legend of the box are separated by a breakpage.
I want to avoid that, but to let the box breakable in its content.
I tried different things, including suppressing the linebreak between the content and the legend (even if it is like a second best option), but I suppose I am doing it wrong.
Here is an example of the situation :
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\newtcolorbox{carnetethno}[1][]{
    breakable, %pour casser les boîtes sur deux pages
    empty,
    before upper*={
        \newcommand{\transfert}{#1}
        \setstretch{1.1}
        \par\noindent\nobreak
    },
    after upper*={
        \par\textsc{\transfert}
    },
}

\begin{document}

    \section{Example}

\lipsum[1-3] \\

Bla~~\\

\begin{carnetethno}[Here the legend]

\lipsum[1]

\end{carnetethno}

\end{document}


You can add \nopagebreak just before the legend:
\newtcolorbox{carnetethno}[1][]{
    breakable, %pour casser les boîtes sur deux pages
    empty,
    before upper*={
        \newcommand{\transfert}{#1}
        \setstretch{1.1}
        \par\noindent\nobreak
    },
    after upper*={
        \nopagebreak\par\textsc{\transfert}% <-- prevent page break before
    },
}

By the way, you can also handle the legend with the title key. To put it below the box, use detach title; the title text is then available with \tcbtitletext and the formatted title with \tcbtitle. I suggest to define your tcolorbox with:
\newtcolorbox{carnetethno}[1][]{
    breakable, %pour casser les boîtes sur deux pages
    empty,
    before upper*={
        \setstretch{1.1}
        \par\noindent\nobreak
    },
    detach title,
    fonttitle=\scshape,
    coltitle=black,
    after upper*={
        \nopagebreak\par\tcbtitle
    },
    #1
}

I put the argument #1 at the end, so you can set extra options to one particular box.
Full example:
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\newtcolorbox{carnetethno}[1][]{
    breakable, %pour casser les boîtes sur deux pages
    empty,
    before upper*={
        \setstretch{1.1}
        \par\noindent\nobreak
    },
    detach title,
    fonttitle=\scshape,
    coltitle=black,
    after upper*={
        \nopagebreak\par\tcbtitle
    },
    #1
}

\begin{document}

    \section{Example}

\lipsum[1-3] \\

% Bla~~\\

\begin{carnetethno}[title={Here the legend}]

\lipsum[1]

\end{carnetethno}

\begin{carnetethno}[title={Here the legend}, coltitle=red]

\lipsum[1]

\end{carnetethno}

\end{document}


